# ASP.NET CORE 2.2 with Jenkins

Tags: c#, http, jenkins, asp.net-core, automation

In my .net core I have simple post action looks like:

```
    [HttpPost("create")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateVm(VirtualMachine vm)
    {
        if (await _repo.VmExists(vm.Name))
            return BadRequest("VM name already exists");

        vm.Hypervisor = _context.Hypervisors.SingleOrDefault(x => x.HypervisorId == 
          vm.HypervisorId);
        vm.Project = _context.Projects.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == vm.ProjectId);
        vm.Management = _context.Managements.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == vm.ManagementId);

        try
        {
            await _context.VirtualMachines.AddAsync(vm);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

I want to implement Jenkins to this method. Logic is Jenkins will check all data and after that data will be saved to database. We have already Jenkins url which I tested via postman everything working fine. What is the best way implement this logic?

Answer (score 0):

Simply after the standard process build, test, deploy create additional build step to make request to that endpoint.
If you do it before the deploy, you have to make sure you have the API and DB up which sounds more complicated. Hope that helps!